# Tax and National Insurance Savings if non-resident (UK)

Tags: income-tax, united-kingdom, national-insurance

I'm working for an employer in London. There is an option for me to work partially from home which means also abroad (EU). I'm considering arriving in the UK on Monday in the morning and leaving on Wednesday in the evening (spending 2 nights only). In this way I might reduce my stay in the UK to less than 90 days per year.

I'm aware that for the non-resident status some additional requirements are needed. Let's assume that I meet them. Thus I would be UK non-resident working Monday till Wednesday in the UK. What would be the amount of tax and National Insurance saved in this case?

Comment: Are you sure your proposed arrangement w.r.t. number of days stayed in the UK would not run afoul of the deeming rule outlined here? https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/547118/160803_RDR3_August2016_v2_0final_078500.pdf

Comment: If you live in the EU 5 days a week you are almost certainly resident there for tax purposes, which means you are going to pay tax on your UK income in your home if you don't pay it in the UK.

Answer (score 1):

[Even non-residents have to pay tax on their UK income](https://www.gov.uk/tax-uk-income-live-abroad), so it probably wouldn't save you tax on your salary:

> You usually have to pay tax on your UK income even if you’re not a UK resident. Income includes things like:
>
> [...]
>
> wages

I can't find a clear reference about National Insurance, but it looks like you would probably [still be liable for it](https://www.gov.uk/tax-come-to-uk#national-insurance):

> You’ll usually pay National Insurance if you work in the UK.

You might save some tax on any foreign income (e.g. interest on savings), but the UK has double-taxation agreements with most or all EU countries anyway so you'd only save if the tax rate of the country you were living in is lower than the UK's rate.